# Combining models within a single page in the admin page

Tags: django

I have a User class, and each user has a PersonalInformation model and a Profile model.

In my admin panel I have:

AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION
Users
Groups

USERS
Profiles
Personal Informations

Users have a ONE-ONE relationship with 'PersonalInformation' and 'Profile', but the two models do not have a relationship.

So I can view the Users, the PersonalInformation and Profile models separately, but I want to join them so I can view all one users information on one page.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you make a `PersonalInformation` model *and* a `Profile` model? Why not one model with a 1-1 to the `User`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example, there actually two quite different models ONE-ONE with a user. I just used profile/personalInfo as examples. Its actually personalInformation (name,date of birth) and Results (school results etc). Theyre quite different and also have many fields so i thought it would make sense to use two seperate models.. or should i combine them?